# VS2010 unit tests fail on TFS 2008 build server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, tfs, msbuild, mstest

The problem is similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624520/running-vs2010-unittests-project-from-tfs2008-team-build), but I have yet to find a solution.

Setup:

- TFS build server is installed on a Win Server 2003 SP2 virtual machine
- It has Visual Studio 2008 Professional on it, as well as Team Suite to publish tests
- We have a .NET 3.5 solution

Running and publishing unit tests using this setup **worked**.  We now want to upgrade to VS2010, without upgrading TFS.

I upgraded the solution to .NET 4.0, set every project's target framework to .NET 4, installed the .NET framework 4.0 on the TFS build server and edited the `MSBuildPath` value in TfsBuildService.exe.config to point to the 4.0 version of `msbuild`.  After changing the build file's `ToolsVersion` to 4.0, the builds worked, but the builds would not run any tests (obviously, since VS2010 wasn't installed at this point).

After installing VS2010 Professional, however, all builds stopped working.  I got them working again after recreating the build definitions, but even after installing Team Explorer 2010, the tests aren't running as `mstest` is complaining about invalid switches passed to it. The message from the log is below:

```
The "TestToolsTask" task is using "MSTest.exe" from "E:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe".
  Invalid switch "/publish".
  Invalid switch "/publishbuild".
  Invalid switch "/teamproject".
  Invalid switch "/platform".
  Invalid switch "/flavor".
```

I thought installing Team Explorer 2010 was supposed to take care of this. Has anyone encountered this before, and fixed it?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install Visual Studio 2010 Premium or Ultimate on the build server to get those options to work.  The edition of mstest in VS Pro does not have them.

Buck