# Error when running unit tests from MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, msbuild

I have an MS Build script that runs on the build server and then runs unit tests (have runtests set to true).

I am getting the following errors when calling MSTest. Some people suggested installing Visual Studio 2010 Test Edition and Team Explorer 2010. After doing that am still getting the same errors. Seems I need a specific version of MSTest to be able to publish to TFS.

Any ideas?

```
===========================================================
The "TestToolsTask" task is using "MSTest.exe" from "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe".
  Invalid switch "/publish".
  Invalid switch "/publishbuild".
  Invalid switch "/teamproject".
  Invalid switch "/platform".
  Invalid switch "/flavor".
  For switch syntax, type "MSTest /help"
MSBUILD : warning MSB6006: "MSTest.exe" exited with code 1.
===========================================================
```

Comment: What is the command you are using to automate the mstest step?

Comment: Can you show full comman line path which was executed before the error? Looks like you are passing MSBuild command line parameters to the MSTest.exe

Answer (score 1):

Try installing VS2010 Premium or Ultimate, these include a version of MSTest that supports the switches for publishing test results. See also [Running VS2012 unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510935/running-vs2012-unit-tests-from-tfs2010-team-build) or [Running VS2010 unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624520/running-vs2010-unittests-project-from-tfs2008-team-build).