# TFS2013 MsTest, invalid switch

Tags: msbuild

I've recently moved to TFS213, did an install on a new machine.

After building one of my projects the result showed an error on MsTest. It turned out that it had invalid switches (as in [Error when running unit tests from MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948094/error-when-running-unit-tests-from-msbuild))

Invalid switch "/publish".
Invalid switch "/publishbuild".
Invalid switch "/teamproject".
Invalid switch "/platform".
Invalid switch "/flavor".

I have found various posts online about this and have done the following :

I have installed vs2013 professional on the build-machine, in various posts it's says to install ultimate but I don't have a license for ultimate.

The problem still persists, the MsTest.exe is started from the correct location (it's only installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE, and the build-process does find the MsTest executable.

for now I've disabled testing in my build-definition but that's not the 'ideal' situation ;-).

Should I just remove the invalid 'switches' or is there some other solution

TIA,
Jurjen.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and solved it by modifying the properties of the "Run MSTest for Test Assemblies" step in the build.

Summary of fix: I changed the Flavor, Platform and Publish properties of the "Run MSTest for Test Assemblies" step to "" (empty string).

Details of fix: I did this in a custom template but I think you could also make the change in the default template.

- Disabled tests (as you did) to make sure my build would work as a baseline.
- Followed instructions here to create and use to a custom template:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx
- Tested that the Custom Template worked by adding a "Write Build Message" step to the build (per advice in article above).
- Searched for (drilled down) to the "Run MSTest for Test Assemblies" step in the build.  This took a long time because it is deep.  I am sure there is a faster way to find it but I am not sure how.
- Set Flavor, Platform and Publish properties to "" (empty string). (See photo).
- Committed template changes to TFS.
- Re-ran the build and it worked.

When all tests pass I don't see test results on the build results screen.
When a test fails it causes the build to fail.  I don't see the test failure in the build summary but it does show up when I click "View Log".

This isn't ideal, but at least I have the tests running and preventing a build from passing when a test fails.

[image: VS 2013 TFS Build MSTest Settings]