# TFS XAML MSTest Path

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, tfs, mstest

I'm using TFS XAML to run my builds. (TFS 2012).
Part of the process is running MSTest to run the unit tests. The MSTest.exe is called from Visual Studio path on the build server.

The problem is that the MSTest is being called from the wrong version of Visual studio. It is calling:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe
```

I'd like it to call:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe
```

Where do / can I specify the version location of the MSTest.exe executable that I want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0" is Visual Studio 2012 folder.

[image]

Do you have the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" directory in the server?

**EDIT: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510935/running-vs2012-unit-tests-from-tfs2010-team-build) (check lordkain's answer and comments).**

> You'll need to change the build template's MSTest activity which may
>   be located in several locations depending on your template. In the
>   default template the activity is labelled "Run MSTest for Metadata
>   File" or "Run MSTest for Test Assembly".
>
> Go to it's properties and change the ToolPath to C":\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE"

Comment: Yes I know that is the directory of visual studio. I have both versions installed for compatibility with older builds. I would like my new build to use the latest visual studio which is 12.0 instead of the default 11.0. I'm therefore looking for the place where to set the version or change the path.

Comment: Oh, I see. Check if the update on my answer works for you :)
@user3177615

Comment: Thanks, that worked. For completeness, I had to ADD the ToolPaath tag as it wasn't there before:  ToolPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe"